# Is it possible to run sdl2-config on Windows?

Tags: shell, sdl, sdl-2

It seems there are several times when running the sdl2-config script bundled with SDL2 would be useful (such as checking which libraries need to be linked to). But it doesn't seem possible to run this script natively on Windows.

I'm using I've been using mingw for all my C compiling needs so far, if that helps. Is there any way I can run this script on Windows?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, sure!

However, that script is just a Bash script, so you need to install Cygwin which has Bash built in. It is **not** recommended to use the native (Win10) port of the Bash shell, since it is not behaving as expected.

If you don't already have it installed, then the tricky part is how to install SDL2 using Cygwin. IMHO, that should probably be avoided, as it tend to cause a lot of weird problems (for other packages).

However, there is already a Cygwin package if you want to try it.

```sh
apt-cyg install mingw64-x86_64-SDL2 libSDL2-devel libSDL2_2.0_0  # etc
```